# php move_uploaded_file не работает с переменной типа $_POST

Tags: php, post

Не могу понять в чем дело, так работает:

```
$str = '1';

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/".$str."/".$_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    $status = 1;
}
```

А вот так не работает:

```
$str = $_POST['id_product'];

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/".$str."/".$_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    $status = 1;
}
```

Comment: Ошибку выдает? подозреваю что просто папки нет такой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего, у вас есть папка `upload/1`, а вот папки `upload/{$_POST['id_product']}` нет, перед тем как туда перемещать, нужно реализовать проверку на существование папки, и если ее нет, создать.

Comment: У меня есть папка upload/1, $_POST['id_product'] = 1

Comment: @ВадимМороз, а может у вас тогда при передаче проблемы, попробуйте во втором случае вывести `$_POST` и `$_FILES` и посмотрите что приходит

Comment: вывожу $_POST он равен единице. единственное, что файлы загружаются плагином, а post передается ajax'ом. аякс подключается раньше плагина

Comment: так у вас запросы отдельно идут получается? я а то плохо понял, вы сделайте дамп двух этих массивов одного нормального запроса на `php скрипт` и посмотрите. Но мне кажется, тут у вас проблема в передаче данных на сервер.